# Generating seed code from existing database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, etl, entity-framework-migrations

I wondered if anyone has encountered a similar challenge:

I have a database with some data that was ETL'ed (imported and transformed) in there from an Excel file. In my ASP.NET MVC web application I'm using Code First approach and dropping/creating every time database changes:

```
#if DEBUG
  Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDataContext>());
#endif
```

However, since the data in the Database is lost, I have to ETL it again, which is annoying.

Since, the DB will be dropped only on model change, I will have to tweak my ETL anyway, I know that. But I'd rather change my DB seed code.

Does anyone know how to take the contents of the database and generate seed code, assuming that both Models and SQL Tables are up to date?

**EDIT 1:**
I'm planning to use the auto-generated Configuration.cs, and its Seed method, and then use `AddOrUpdate()` method to add data into the database: Here is [Microsoft's Tutorial on migrations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases) (specifically the "Set up the Seed method" section).

Comment: What do you mean by "seed code"?

Comment: I added an explanation to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way of seeding data is to run it as sql in an Up migration.

I have code that will read a sql file and run it

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.IO;

public partial class InsertStandingData : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                               .BaseDirectory
                               .Replace("\\bin", string.Empty) + "\\Data\\Sql Scripts";

        Sql(File.ReadAllText(baseDir + "\\StandingData.sql"));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        //Add delete sql here
    }
}
```

So if your ETL generates sql for you then you could use that technique.

The advantages of doing it in the Up method are

1. It will be quicker than doing it using `AddOrUpdate` because
   `AddOrUpdate` queries the database each time it is called to get any
   already existing entity.
2. You are normally going from a known state (e.g. empty tables) so you probably
   don't need to check whether data exists already. NB to ensure this
   then you should delete the data in the `Down` method so that you can
   tear all the way down and back up again.
3. The Up method does not run every time the application starts.

The Seed method provides convenience - and it has the advantage (!?) that it runs every time the application starts

But if you prefer to run the sql from there use `ExecuteSqlCommand` instead of `Sql`:

```
string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin", string.Empty) 
              + "\\Data\\Sql Scripts";
string path = Path.Combine(baseDir, "StandingData");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.sql"))
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(file));
}
```

References:

[Best way to incrementally seed data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344260/150342)

[Preparing for database deployment](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases)

[Database Initializer and Migrations Seed Methods](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/)

Comment: What namespace is the Sql method from?

Comment: It's in the same namespace as `DbMigration`! Answer edited to show the class and using statements

Comment: So Up and Down methods run only on database drop?

Comment: They run when you call Update-Database http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621

Comment: Will this work if you're only seeding one table from the database?

Answer (score 12):

Lets say we have a simple database table with **3750** records in it;

```
| Id   | Age | FullName        |
|------|-----|-----------------|
| 1    | 50  | Michael Jackson |
| 2    | 42  | Elvis Presley   |
| 3    | 48  | Whitney Houston |
| ...  | ... | ...             |
| 3750 | 57  | Prince          |
```

We want to create this table in our database with using auto-generated `Configuration.cs` file and its `Seed()` method.

```
protected override void Seed(OurDbContainer context)
{
    context.GreatestSingers.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Id,
            new GreatestSinger { Id = 1, Age = 50, FullName = "Michael Jackson" },
            new GreatestSinger { Id = 2, Age = 42, FullName = "Elvis Presley" },
            new GreatestSinger { Id = 3, Age = 48, FullName = "Whitney Houston" }
            );
}
```

This is what you should do. **3750** times!

But you already have this data in your **existing database table**. So we can use this **existing** data to create `Seed()` codes.

With the help of **[SQL String Concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)**;

```
SELECT
CONCAT('new GreatestSinger { Id = ', Id ,', Age = ', Age ,', FullName = "', FullName ,'" },') 
FROM GreatestSinger
```

will give us all the code needed to create **3750** rows of data.

Just copy/paste it into `Seed()` method. And from **Package Manager Console**;

```
Add-Migration SeedDBwithSingersData

Update-Database
```