# Entity Framework Bulk Load Too Slow Add Seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulk-load

```
    protected override void Seed(Fitlife.Domain.Concrete.EFDBContext context)
    {
        List<List<string>> foodweights = GetLines(basePath + "FoodWeights.txt");
        int counter = 0;
        foodweights.ForEach(line =>
        {
            FoodWeights newVal = new FoodWeights()
            {
                 FoodCode = int.Parse(line[0]),
                  PortionCode = int.Parse(line[1]),
                 PortionWeight = decimal.Parse(line[2])
            };
            context.FoodWeights.Add(newVal);

            if (++counter == 1000)
            {
                counter = 0;
                context.SaveChanges();                  
            }
        });
}
```

Above method is used to populate my database. But it takes 50 seconds for 1000 entries i have a file with 470k entries, how can i improve performance i am using entity framework and this method is called when i do 
PM> update-database
with Package manager. i need similar functionality, i am very new to asp.net and entity framework any guidance will be appreciated thanks.

PS: Is it ok to take 50 seconds for 1000 entries or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately EF doesn't play well with batch/bulk jobs. I'd just use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), which was designed for mass inserts.

Comment: can you provide me with any example i can use sqlbulkcopy inside my seed function, i want to still be able to use package manager command like
PM> update-database

Comment: How many records does FoodWeights.txt contain? I see that your saving every 1000 lines. It looks as if it will still loop through your entire file, which could take quite some time if FoodWeights.txt is a large file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Seed method runs every time the application starts, so the way you have coded it will attempt to add the `FoodWeight`s over and over again. EF have provided the `AddOrUpdate` as a convenient method to prevent that but it is really not appropriate for bulk inserts.

You could use sql directly on the database - and if you are using sql server that sql could be ['BULK INSERT'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

I would put the sql in an Up migration because you probably only want to run the insert once from a known state, and it avoids having to worry about the efficiency of the context and tracking changes etc.

There is example code and more information here: [how to seed data using sql files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19267917/150342)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i used SqlBulkInsert and its fast, i will put the seed in up migration, but what is the purpose of my overriden seed function, does it have a convenience.

Comment: I posted more on this answer - with links to more reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/19267917/150342